# Why does my equation for ballistic trajectory not work?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

Recently I have been working on the problem of calculating a ballistic trajectory. I landed on the following equation: $y = tan(θ)x - gt^2 $, where $θ$ is the launch angle, $x$ is the distance travelled horizontally, g is 9.81, t is time and y is the height relative to the starting position after having travelled x distance horizontally. However, the problem I am having is that as θ increases so does y after x distance travelled, which does not correctly model real-world behaviour. There should be a point at which launching the object at a higher angle decreases the height after x distance travelled. I have previously seen equations involving other trig functions when calculating a ballistic trajectory, but I wanted a good explanation as to why this is needed.

Comment: If you are given $x$ and wish to find the point $(x,y)$ on the trajectory, how do you get the value of $t$, which you also need in order to apply your formula?

Comment: x/v where v is velocity

Comment: Ok thanks I will put it up there

Comment: Your error is that $t \neq x/v$ because the projectile is not just moving along the $x$ axis.

Comment: @DavidK Also note that $v$ is time-dependent.

Comment: I guess your equation came from $ y = vt \sin\theta - \frac 12 gt^2$, with $vt = x/\cos\theta$. If you actually substitute the remaining $t$ (in the $-\frac 12 gt^2$) too, you might get something that better link $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @junjios Yes, because of the varying $y$-component, although the usual method is just to correctly compute the $x$ component, which is constant.

Answer (score 2):

With the given acceleration and initial speed and position:
$$
\ddot r(t)=(0,-g)\\
\dot r_0=(v_0\cos(\theta),v_0\sin(\theta))\\
r_0=(0,0)
$$
the integration gives:
$$
\dot r(t)=(v_0\cos(\theta),v_0\sin(\theta)-gt) \\
r(t)=(v_0\cos(\theta)t,v_0\sin(\theta)t-\frac12 gt^2) 
$$
so the horizontal and vertical position are:
$$
x(t)=v_0\cos(\theta)t\\
y(t)=v_0\sin(\theta)t-\frac12 gt^2
$$

And the last expression can be written as:
$$
y(t)=\tan(\theta)x(t)-\frac12 gt^2
$$
or better, replacing the $t$:
$$
y=\tan(\theta)x- \frac{g}{2v_0^2\cos(\theta)^2}x^2
$$

The last is a function for a parabola with negative convexity in the xy plane.